# How can we get the impression shown on YouTube Studio using YouTube Analytics API?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-analytics-api

I'm creating YouTube's metrics monitoring feature. But I faced one confusing point while using YouTube Analytics API.

I want to retrieve a video impression shown on YouTube Studio using YouTube Analytics API.
I'm using the following dimensions/metrics:

- dimension

  - day
- metrics

  - annotationImpressions
  - annotationClickableImpressions
  - annotationClosableImpressions
  - cardImpressions
  - cardTeaserImpressions

But the value of the total impression of the above metrics is not matching with YouTube Studio's one.
("views" is matching on both, so the date range is correct, I think)

YouTube Studio's value on 2021-01-04
[image: YouTube Studio value]

Youtube Analytics API's response on 2021-01-04 (I called the API from "Try it!" form with the above dimension and metrics)
https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/reference/reports/query?apix=true

```json
{
  "kind": "youtubeAnalytics#resultTable",
  "columnHeaders": [
    {
      "name": "day",
      "columnType": "DIMENSION",
      "dataType": "STRING"
    },
    {
      "name": "views",
      "columnType": "METRIC",
      "dataType": "INTEGER"
    },
    {
      "name": "annotationImpressions",
      "columnType": "METRIC",
      "dataType": "INTEGER"
    },
    {
      "name": "annotationClickableImpressions",
      "columnType": "METRIC",
      "dataType": "INTEGER"
    },
    {
      "name": "annotationClosableImpressions",
      "columnType": "METRIC",
      "dataType": "INTEGER"
    },
    {
      "name": "cardImpressions",
      "columnType": "METRIC",
      "dataType": "INTEGER"
    },
    {
      "name": "cardTeaserImpressions",
      "columnType": "METRIC",
      "dataType": "INTEGER"
    }
  ],
  "rows": [
    [
      "2021-01-04",
      211,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      5,
      398
    ]
  ]
}
```

Could you tell us the solution how to get the same value of impression as YouTube Studio by using YouTube Analytics API?

Comment: What have you tried so far please include your code.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I wrote the point that I called the API from the API reference page's "Try it!" form.

Comment: [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71490683) on a similarStackOverflow question seems to solve this problem.